# Make GDB to avoid some source files during stepping

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

Is there way to make **GDB** to avoid some headers (e.g. STL's) or even a part of whole source directory? Somtimes it is very hindering thing, when **GDB** steps through a bunch of non-interested code, even through STL's one-liners, concentrated into known at debug time location (source file, separate source files, whole path). I want **GDB** to step over over all the invocations of functions from specified source files as over some atomic statements, without entering into its internals.

Comment: Recent GDB are scriptable in Python or Guile. So you could write such a script.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I look for simple solution like command line or `.gdbinit` key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there way to make GDB to avoid some headers

Yes, this has been added to recent GDB versions. See `skip` command [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files.html).